# Parse.com How to return a value from a query in Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, return-value

I'm using the `Parse API` to query some data for an Android application and I would like to know how to return a value (for example a `Boolean`) from a `Parse Query`. For example I would like a function that returns `true` if some data exists and `false` otherwise like so :

```
    public Boolean myFunction(){
      ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery();
      query.findInBackground("someData",new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject lan, ParseException e) {
            if(e==null){
              return true;
            } else {
              return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

I do know that this cannot be done this way because the query is processed in a background thread and I'm not very familiar with `Callbacks`.
I am aware that there is a similar question here [Parse.com how to get return value of query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422069/parse-com-how-to-get-return-value-of-query) but this is for `JavaScript`. 
Do you have any idea on how to do that ?

Comment: You could explore looking at a bit of cloud code that just returns your boolean result. This should save having to download the data locally.
http://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/

Comment: @buckettt thanks I will look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and thanks to @buckettt, the easiest way to accomplish that is to use `Parse Cloud Code`. Define your function in the `main.js` file inside `parse-server` folder :

```js
Parse.Cloud.define("myFunction",function(req,res){
   var userId = req.params.userId; //params passed in Client code
   var myQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
   myQuery.equalTo("userId", userId);
   myQuery.find({
      success: function(results) {
          res.success(results.get("userName"));
      }
      error: function() {
         res.error("Failed !");
      }
   }

});
```

And in your Client's code :

```
    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("userId",userId);
    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("myFunction", params, new FunctionCallback<String>() {
        public void done(String res,ParseException e){
            if (e == null) {
                Log.i("Results :",res);
            } else {
                Log.i("Error",e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

This way you return the desired value and the function is executed directly on your server. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. When you get the Parse Object extract it with:

```
boolean myBoolean = myParseObject.getBoolean("myBooleanColumn");
```

Full example (finding an object via id, it can be adapted for other type of queries):

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("YourClass");
query.getInBackground("id", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject myParseObject, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      boolean myBoolean = myParseObject.getBoolean("myBooleanColumn");
    } else {
      // something went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

Update: if you only want to check if some data exists in a row you can do it with

```
query.whereEqualTo("columnToFind", "searchterm");
```

You can even find compare an array with the data in row with

```
query.whereContainsAll("columnToFind", arrayOfThingsToSearch);
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I want to do. I don't want to get data from a parse object but check if some data exists in some row. Then I could use if(!myFunction) then do something